# AJAX + PHP, получение нескольких переменных из базы данных

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Через AJAX выполняется скрипт php, который успешно берет множество переменных из бд
Вопрос:
 как вывести это множество переменных на свои места в странице сайта?

```js
$(".Order").click(function(){
    var Id;
    var x = $(this).find('span');
    Id = x.text();
    history.pushState(null, null, '/cmb_project/userclient.php?n='+Id);
    
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        url: "php/vieworder.php",
         data: {numkek:Id}
}).done(function( result )
        {
           
        });
});
```

Comment: как определяются их места? какие признаки?

Comment: Внесите декларацию `var Id;` внутрь обработчика `click`.

Comment: в HTML странице для этих переменных уже заготовлены места, через id и классы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам просто передать массив переменных, то в php возвращаете массив в jsone

```
return json_encode($result);
```

и на js разбираете его на переменные

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Так, с PHP Я понял, что делать
а куда вставлять эту строчку в js?
за место: .done(function( result ){}
и в скобках уже разбирать?

Comment: А зачем парсить, если можно указать среди параметров AJAX-запроса `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: @Byulent , хорошо, указал
но что тогда дальше делать, Я не могу понять как работать с полученными данными, написал еще параментр succses и error, вылетает еррор, но Я все еще не понимаю, что не так\

Comment: @GicO, значит, вы всё-таки не совсем поняли, что нужно делать с PHP. Нужно как-то обработать выходящую ошибку и посмотреть, что там, затем исправить её для получения валидного JSON'а. Но сейчас я уже не помню, как это делал.